# Seperate input boxes on the same line - Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a contact form in figma that I'm trying to recreate using Flexbox. The form consists of 4 inputs which are "Name", "Phone", "Email" and "Message.

The name field is 828px wide. Phone and email fields are 406px wide.

I want the phone and email fields on the same row with 16px margin between them. On the next row will be the message field that is 828px wide.

The form is inside a container that is 828px wide with display set to flex.

How can I put the phone and email on the same row? I've attached a screen shot to show how my form currently looks. P.S I know there's redundent code in terms of styling. I'll clean it up later. 
[image]

```css
.form {
 margin: 75px auto;
 max-width: 828px;
 display: flex;
}
.home-name {
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 width: 828px;
 height: 38px;
 padding: 14px auto;
}

.home-phone {
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 406px;
 height: 38px;
}

.home-email {
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 406px;
 height: 38px;
}

.home-message {
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 828px;
 height: 167px;
}
```

```html
 
 <html>
 <head>
 <body>
 
 <div class="form">
                        <div>
                            <div class="name-form">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name" required>
                            </div>
                        
                            <div class="phone-form">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone" required>
                            </div>
                
                            <div class="email-form">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="home-email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="message-form">
                                <textarea placeholder="Message" class="home-message" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button class="home-message-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                    
 </html>
 </head>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code below for details change. I added `flex-wrap: wrap;` and change `max-width: 828px;` to `width: 828px;` on class `.form`. I cleaned up the HTML code by removing one unnecessary `<div>`.

```css
.form {
  margin: 75px auto;
  width: 828px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  width: 828px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 14px auto;
}

.home-phone {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 406px;
  height: 38px;
}

.home-email {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 406px;
  height: 38px;
}

.home-message {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 828px;
  height: 167px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">

  <div class="name-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name" required>
  </div>

  <div class="phone-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone" required>
  </div>

  <div class="email-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="home-email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="message-form">
    <textarea placeholder="Message" class="home-message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="home-message-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add these code to your style

```
.phone-form ,.email-form{

    float:left;
}
.email-form{
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```